# How to update without replacing existing data in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to update a field and value in mongodb without replacing the current one?
this is the current database

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('5rac6e8c9cb4081f5c637074')
  "name": "crystal"
  "color": "green"
  "namesOfbooks": {
    "redhood": 1,
  },
}
```

i tried this

```
db.update({name: "crystal"},{ $set: { namesOfbooks: { "cakemaking": 5 } }})
```

but getting this result below, the previous `"redhood": 1` was replace

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('5rac6e8c9cb4081f5c637074')
  "name": "crystal"
  "color": "green"
  "namesOfbooks": {
    "cakemaking": 5,
  },
}
```

how to instead keep the previous `"redhood": 1,` with the new `"cakemaking": 5` like this below?

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('5rac6e8c9cb4081f5c637074')
  "name": "crystal"
  "color": "green"
  "namesOfbooks": {
    "redhood": 1,
    "cakemaking": 5
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be like this :

```
db.getCollection('YourCollection').update({name: "crystal"},
{ $set: { 'namesOfbooks.cakemaking': 5 }})
```

but not this :

```
db.getCollection('YourCollection').update({name: "crystal"},{ $set: { namesOfbooks: { "cakemaking": 5 } }})
```

Difference would be you're actually updating the attribute **namesOfbooks** on a whole rather than just update attributes inside **namesOfbooks**, nested keys inside an object can be accessed via `.` notation as like in programming languages.

Comment: hi thank you @srinivasy but what if the ```'cakemaking': 5 ``` was in a variable like this  ```const cake = {"cakemaking": 5}```how would you access the string ```'cakemaking'```  to use in the dot notation?

Comment: @Manny : Do you get multiple values like ::: const cake = {"cakemaking": 5, "cakeBaking":10} or just one key-value pair (as what you've given above) in cake object ?

Comment: there is one key-value pair in a object but there are more than one objects @srinivasy

Comment: @manny : Is that key a dynamic thing in those objects/documents or same ‘cakemaking’ ? Also those objects has to be updated in namesOfbooks attribute of single document ?

Comment: yes the keys are dynamic and the objects are updated in different documents @srinivasy

Comment: @Manny  : You might need to try this way : { $set: { ['namesOfbooks.' + Object.keys(cake)]: cake.cakemaking }} or similar one : { $set: { ['namesOfbooks.' + Object.keys(cake)]: Object.values(cake)[0] }}